# Odd behavior when binding a click to two elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have two images with the title "Show Options". I want to assign a click event to both of them and I want the clicks to print different statements.

```
 console.log($('img[title*=\"Show\"]'));
  $('img[title*=\"Show\"]').each(function(index, value){
    switch(index){
        case 0:
            console.log('object');
            $(this).live('click', function(e) {
                console.log('object clicked');
            });
        break;

        case 1:
            console.log('record');
            $(this).live('click', function(e) {
                console.log('record clicked');
            });
        break;
    }
  });
```

ODD BEHAVIOR

1. `object` and `record` are printed so I know there are 2 elements.
2. When I click on the image that is associated with object, `record` is printed.
3. When I click on the image that is associated with record, nothing is printed.

I am not sure how I can resolve this.

Comment: From the looks of it, smells like an indexing issue. See if changing `case 0:` to `case 1:` and changing `case 1:` to `case 2:` will solve the issue. Then you need to find out whether this is how jQuery indexes the items when using `each` or that you might have an extra `img` element somewhere on the page that comes before the other two.

Comment: Interesting. When I change it to Case 1 and Case 2, object clicked gets printed, and nothing happens when I click the 2nd image. Also object and record are no longer printed.

Comment: I added a console.log on the expression im matching, and I can confirm only 2 images are being returned.

Comment: Why are you using `live` to bind your click event?  Since you're attaching the click event to a known object in the DOM (i.e. the image at the current `each` iteration) I don't see the benefit.  I replaced it with `bind` in a fiddle and everything worked smoothly: http://jsfiddle.net/FVSUV/

Comment: It would help to see your html code.

Comment: @Pat I would totally have upvoted this if you had posted it as an answer ;) `live()` seems to take selectors only.

Comment: @Pat: That's a (good) answer, not a comment: ["Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector, as in the example above."](http://api.jquery.com/live/#caveats)

Comment: Was being careful as I wasn't sure if there was something about `live` I'd missed in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the `.live` method is to allow you to specify event handlers on DOM objects that may change, or do not yet exist. This works because in fact no handler is attached at all. Instead, a pre-existing handler at the root of the document looks through all of the selectors registered with `.live()` to determine if any of them is a match.

In your example, you are passing in a DOM object directly, and not a jQuery selector. So, what's probably happening (although, I'm not sure) is that it's trying to attach live events to selectors created by stringifying the DOM objects, which can lead to strange, unexpected results.

If you're trying to attach events to a single DOM object that will not change, just use the `.bind()` function.

If you really needed to use live, you could restructure the code so that you specify selectors that match the elements. For example:

```
var selector = 'img[title*=\"Show\"]';
$(selector).each(function(index, value){
    switch(index){
        case 0:
            console.log('object');
            $(selector+":eq(0)").live('click', function(e) {
                console.log('object clicked');
            });
        break;

        case 1:
            console.log('record');
            $(selector+":eq(1)").live('click', function(e) {
                console.log('record clicked');
            });
        break;
    }
});
```

In general, this is a very bad pattern, and there are much more eloquent ways to do things. However, it is in theory possible to make this pattern work.